# Is this union of open sets an open set?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Queston:

> $Y = \{(0, y) ∈ E^2: −1 < y < 1\}$ ,
>
> $Z = \left\{\left(x,\sin(1/x)\right) ∈ E^2: 0 < x ≤ 1\right\} ,$
>
> $X = Y ∪ Z$.
>
> Is $X$ an open subset of $E^2$?
>
> Is $X$ a connected subset of $E^2$?
>
> Justify your answers.

Is it enough to say that  of $Z$ and $Y$ are collections of open intervals of in $E^2$, so their union must also be?

Also since these two sets are open and their union is the entire space then the set is not connected by definition.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should reconsider whether these sets are open.

Comment: For set braces please type `\{...\}`. What is your definition of open?

Comment: My apologies, I've added them.

Comment: Generally In my course if a specific topology isn't mentioned were to presume it is the standard topology.

Comment: @MJD: the set $Y $ is the segment joining $(0,-1) $ and $ (0,1) $.

Comment: It would be, if that were true, but it isn't.  As MJD points out $(a,b) \in E^2$ means that $(a,b)$ is an ordered pair $a \in E; b \in E$ and not the interval of of {x$\in E$| a< x < b} $\subset of E$.  Which is *not* a subset of $E^2$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami No it isn't. To interpret Y as a set of intervals would mean $Y \subset P(E)\ne E^2$ and can not be determined whether it is open or not unless you define a topology on $P(E)$.  $\{(x,y)| \text{(x,y) is an interval in E}\}$$ \ne \cup_{\text{(x,y) is an interval in E}} (x,y)$.  That iterpretation simply won't make sense.

Comment: @fleablood: yes it is. I have no idea what you mean by "set of intervals". But I suggest you draw a picture of $Y$ in the plane, and you'll see that it is indeed the segment joining $(0,-1)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: Oops.  I misunderstood what you were trying to say. $Y=\{0\}\times (-1,1)$ which is a line segment in a plane. It isn't a union of two separate intervals in E. But the OP was interpreting it as $Y = \{(0,y) = \{x| 0< x < y\} \subset E| -1< y< 1\}$ (wrong) and further was assuming $\{(0,y)\} = \cup (0,y)$ (wrong) which would be $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$ . Which I mistakenly thought you were trying to say.  MJD pointed this out. You appeared to be correcting MJD (who was correct) and supporting to OP (who was wrong). I was mistaken. My apologies.

Comment: See.  If we were to *incorrectly* assume (as the OP did) that $(a,b) = \{x|a < x < b\}$ then we would have $Y = \{(0,y)|-1< 0< 1\} \subset  P(E)$ which is *entirely* different than $Y \subset E^2$.  Furthermore if $Y$ as a *set* of open intervals, is completely different than $Y$ as a *union* of open intervals (which is a subset of $E$; not a subset of $P(E)$).  A union of open intervals would be open.  A *set* of open intervals would require that a topology be defined on $P(E)$ and that topology could be ... anything.

Comment: Furthermore, in no way does $X\cup Y = E^2$.  But $[\cup_{-1< y<1}(0,y)] \cup [\cup_{0< x \le 1}(x, \sin 1/x)]= \mathbb R$.  (If we assume $(a,b) = (b,a) $ is $a> b$ and $E = \mathbb R$).  All of this indicated to me that the OP was mistaking what the notation $(a,b)$ meant.  Which simply wouldn't not work for several reasons.  (i) $E^2 \ne E \ne P(E)$ ii) $\{(a,b)\} \ne \cup (a,b)$, and iii)$ (a, b); b< a$ isn't defined (although it could be for notational purposes).

Comment: @fleablood: fair enough. Only now I see the OP's interpretation. Somehow I never confuse intervals with points, I guess the context is always clear enough.

Comment: Yeah, well....I don't usually either but when I do or I see someone who does it's usually a doozy. The context $(a,b) \in E^2$ is, by definition stating $(a,b)$ is an ordered pair and interpreting it as an interval is just not an option.  $(a,b) \subset \mathbb R$ indicate it is a set of real number singletons and interpreting it as an ordered pair is not an option.  I have seen the confusion that if $(a,b) = \{x|a < x < b\}$ and $(c,d) = \{x|c < d ,b\}$ then $\{(a,b),(c,d)\} = \{x|a < x <b or c < x < d\} = (a,b) \cup (c,d)$ which is  false in the same way $\{\emptyset\} = \emptyset$ is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a mistake that $(a,b)$ does not mean the interval $(a,b) = \{x\in E| a< x<b\}\subset E$.  They mean that $(a,b)$ is the ordered pair $(a,b) = a \times b \in E\times E = E^2$.

So $Y = \{(0,y)| -1 < y < 1\}$ would be the set of all ordered pairs where the first term is $0$ and the second term is in the interval between 0 and 1.  This would be open if we were restricted to just one dimension of $E$ but it is not open in $E^2$ because every neighborhood of $(0,y)$ will contain a point $(x',y')$ where $x' \ne 0$ (but $d((x'y')(0,y)) < \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$) and $(x',y') \not \in Y$.

$Z$ isn't equal for similar reason and neither is $Y\cup Z$.

Answer (score 1):

None of your three sets is open. The point of the exercise is to show that  $X $ is an example of a set that is connected but not path connected.